# Add Button on the top of Salesforce besides Global Search button to open a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce-component

[image]I have a requirement to add a custom button on the top of Salesforce besides Global Search button. Is it possible to add the button and open a visualforce page?

Comment: Where you want, not really...

Comment: @Eric I just edited the post and attached the snapshot. I want the button somewhere around red box.

Comment: The only way to do it I see is to use something like a component on side bar with javascript that populates the button.

Comment: @EvAzi - Is that even possible anymore?

Comment: @EvAzi I think if injecting Javascript is possible then adding button will not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add buttons or custom elements to that region of the classic view. If you want a more 'mobile' user experience with custom navigation, consider switching to Lightning. Adding JS buttons is definitely bad practice with the rollout of Lightning and should be avoided in Classic so you don't limit yourself in the future... good food for thought to bring to your customer or client asking for this.

Comment: Is it impossible to add there or should I research more about it ?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to modify the out of the box SFDC Header in the way you want. You will have to create a custom home page. I would question the use case for doing that however.